# Funq: A DI Container

Tags: funq

I have seen Funq as a DI Container in an example for MVVM.
I tried to find documentation for it but could not.

Does anyone know of a good documentation source for Funq

Many thanks
--Avi

Answer (score 2):

The only time I've seen it used is with Service Stack: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container